# How to set a global variable with CSS var() (without having to set the property of each element?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/9e22zasm/946/

A CSS `var()` is being set by using JavaScript's `setProperty`:

```
// CSS:

:root {
  --footer-color: #2cba92 // default
}

footer {
  background-color: var(--footer-color)
}

// JS:

const footer = document.querySelector('footer')
footer.style.setProperty('--footer-color', 'red')
```

The problem is, I want to set the `var()` of many elements (they will all share the same `var()`):

```
// CSS:

:root {
  --primary-color: #2cba92 // default
}

header {
  background-color: var(--primary-color)
}

section {
  background-color: var(--primary-color)
}

footer {
  background-color: var(--primary-color)
}
```

What's the easier way to change `--primary-color` and change the color of header, section, and footer? Because if I don't find a way, I'll have to change each element one by one:

```
// JS:

const footer = document.querySelector('header')
header.style.setProperty('--primary-color', 'red')

const footer = document.querySelector('section')
section.style.setProperty('--primary-color', 'red')

const footer = document.querySelector('footer')
footer.style.setProperty('--primary-color', 'red')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:root` selector targets the `<html>` node, which is available under `document.documentElement`.

So to modify this variable, set this node's css property:

```js
onclick = e => {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--footer-color', '#FF00FF');
}
```

```css
:root {
  --footer-color: #2cba92;
}

footer {
  background-color: var(--footer-color)
}
```

```html
<footer>hello</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can target the stylesheet itself with `document.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style`.

This will allow you to update the CSS variable, and thus update all of the element's colours with only one `.setProperty()`:

```js
const root = document.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style;
root.setProperty('--primary-color', 'red');
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #2cba92
}

header {
  background-color: var(--primary-color)
}

section {
  background-color: var(--primary-color)
}

footer {
  background-color: var(--primary-color)
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<section>Section</section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Note that `.rules[0]` targets the **first** rule set in your stylesheet; you'll need to ensure that `:root` is at the top of your document.